# Float calculations hangs on Kinetis K20 (arm-m4-no-fpu) when PWM interrupt is on

Tags: microcontroller, c, arm, floating-point

I will use this ARM to control Induction Motor with three-phase inverter. 
When the program encounters any float operations, like simple plus operation, the system hangs but the pause of debug works well.
I increased the stack, I turned types as double, I increased the period that the interrupt ocorre (before 50us, changed to 1ms) however only work when this interrupt is turned off.

Kinetis K20 Without FPU
CodeWarrior 10.4
Timer Overflow period 50uS
Stack greater than 2048b
Combined-complementary PWM mode

Comment: Sounds like the ISR or interrupt dispatch clobbers one or more of the registers used in FP operations.

Comment: Is it fair to ask if you can just avoid using floats?  With int32_t and int64_t, you can just make your units fine enough for integer math to do fine (i.e., instead of 92 degrees, use 92000 thousandths of a degree)?  Unless its something critical like pole placement, this is usually better use of resources than using floats.  You just need to remember to do your multiplies before your divides!

Comment: Second Scott Seidman. One big multiply, a dozen operations and one big divide is computationally much less intensive, and is a common trick for improving the cycle time of things like FFTs.

Comment: @Ignacio, Has ISR/interrupt its own registers on arm architecture or no (I'm not sure)? On disassembly of this interrupt don't have any 'push' instruction.

Comment: @Scott, I contemplated this idea, but what if I need some float operation later? Redo the program is time consuming and this problem may appear in other complex operations of the program.

Comment: @SeanBoddy, especially if you can work out your scaling in advance to make all of your divides are powers of two shifts!

Comment: @fabio, all I can say is that its very rare for me to need to do floating point ops on an embedded platform.  All of my inputs from every peripheral are ints, all of my multipliers are ints (even if I need to scale them up), my PWM parameters are ints, and so on.  Since I started programming on 8-bit microcontrollers in the '80s, I haven't needed to use a floating point operation.  With 64 bit math, you can get real low fixed point errors if you toss floats right out of your toolbox.

Comment: @Scott Seidman, I understand your point. I have made this some three-phase inverter on S08PA (8-bit) with various shift, and int operation (scaling down const SIN TABLE on FLASH), but i'm afraid with this 'bug' on future board that controls motor of heavy machines.

Comment: I would also point out that your platform holds up your design. Making the economic decision to use a particular part comes with the responsibility of playing to its strengths. If I read the original post correctly, your platform is not equipped with a floating point unit. If floating point data becomes crucial to the application,  it may be time to reevaluate your choice of platform.

Comment: Especially considering that if an FPU is desired, the higher-end MCUs in the K20 line add it. They're even pin compatible.

Comment: Thanks for all. But i have understand the origem of this problem!

Comment: @fabio so tell us, what WAS the origin on the problem? What was killing your software Floating point maths?

Comment: @KyranF, I Get it! The Processor Expert (wizard of CodeWarrior) don't add '~FTM_CnSC_CHIE_MASK' (Enable/Disable Channel Overflow Interrupt) to disabled channels (6 and 7, motor control use only 0 to 5). Thus interrupts of channels 6 and 7 are fired without proper functions.

Comment: @fabio, I would like to make sure that I understand that completely, for my own benefit. The software floating point works appropriately because you disabled channel 6 and 7, or because you disabled their ability to process an interrupt request? Or both?

Comment: @Sean Boddy, Sorry, but my english is limited. I have two channels disabled 6 and 7 on FTM0 because motors use only 6 channels (0 to 5). There are enabled an interrupt for timer overflow in this FTM0. Flex Timers of Freescale has channel match interrupt for each channel (0 to 7), too. However, I don't use them. But the Wizard Processor Expert that I use only to initialize the FTM0 don't disabled these two interrupts for channels 6 and 7, thus these channels generate interrupts that don't had functions assigned.

Comment: Okay, so the interrupt service routine would hang up when an enabled channel had an empty function; am I correct?

Comment: @Sean Boddy, I saw after that no only float operations are affected: all main thread don't work because these two interrupts generated without an vector address jump to undefined memory location. But when I clear the flag in order to disable all interrupts of FTM, these two interrupts also are disabled.

Comment: @fabio, that makes sense. Thank you for sharing your experience with us!

Comment: I'm glad you got it and I managed to solve the problem!